# How to add Drush to PATH?

Tags: path, drupal

On a CentOS with Bash with MariaDB and PHP 8.1 I use Drush.
Drush is the command line for Drupal, a content management system.

Each time I run a Drush command I write like:

```bash
cd /home/www/example_1.com
vendor/bin/drush status
vendor/bin/drush cache:rebuild
```

or

```bash
cd /home/www/example_2.com
vendor/bin/drush status
vendor/bin/drush cache:rebuild
```

How could I utilize `PATH` to no longer need `vendor/bin` for Drush commands?

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:vendor/bin
```

Is this the way to go?

Comment: What shell are you using, `bash` or `zsh` (or any other)?

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround (and maybe there are better ways) is about updating the `$PATH` every time you get the shell prompt and that's possible by using `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable (in `bash`).

So you can define a function like this:

```bash
#You can modify this function to update the path
#only when the current directory is under '/home/www/website_folder'

checkPath() { 

if [[ -z $OLDPATH ]]; then  
  OLDPATH="$PATH";  
  PATH="${PATH}:${PWD}/vendor/bin"; 
else 
  PATH="${OLDPATH}:${PWD}/vendor/bin"
fi 

}
```

<sup>**The if condition prevents adding a new path every time you run a command. So you will have always your original `$PATH` + `$PWD/vendor/bin` where `$PWD` is the working directory**</sup>

And in your shell set this:

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND='checkPath'
```

With the code above every time you get the shell prompt (when a command finished its execution the `PROMPT_COMMAND` content (checkPath function in this case)  is executed).

So if you type:

```bash
cd /home/www/example_1.com
```

The `$PATH` will have:

```
/home/www/example_1.com/vendor/bin
```

When you change to `example_2.com` like this:

```bash
cd /home/www/example_2.com 
#or 
cd ../example_2.com
```

The `$PATH` will have:

```
/home/www/example_2.com/vendor/bin
```

**Disadvantage**

Using this workaround might be useful but if you change to a directory such as `/home/www` the `$PATH` will have this value:

```bash
/home/www/vendor/bin
```

As you can see, the $PATH might have a non-existent directory but AFAIK this will not have issues with your shell, remember that the PATH is changed every time (when you *cd* to another directory). In case of `/home/www/vendor/bin` exists then the files under that directory will be recognized by the `PATH` variable.

---

Also, if you had `drush` installed globally in your system (e.g. in `/usr/bin`) then the command `drush` provided by `/home/www/example_?.com/vendor/bin/` will not work.

A solution to this is to prepend `${PWD}/vendor/bin` to `$PATH` instead of appending it:

```bash
checkPath() { 

if [[ -z $OLDPATH ]]; then  
  OLDPATH="$PATH";  
  PATH="${PWD}/vendor/bin:${PATH}"; 
else 
  PATH="${PWD}/vendor/bin:${OLDPATH}"
fi 

}
```

Comment: Note that it's in general possible that multiple installations have mutually-incompatible versions and/or the tool tries to guess config files from its own location, so using `/home/www/example1.com/vendor/bin/drush` for `/home/www/example2.com/` might not be safe.

Comment: I have several websites `example_1.com`, `example_2.com` etc.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz just as you said! haha :). Thanks for it!

Comment: @tainu glad you have provided that info in your question. I had no idea about that (it'll better to remove the answer, for now)

Comment: @tainu updated answer